How to export to excel using Laravel Fast-Excel and JavaScript's fetch?
I am currently using Laravel Fast-Excel with the Chunks method: https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/fast-excel?tab=readme-ov-file#export-large-collections-with-chunk
I have the following in my controller:
public function download_excel(Request $request)
{
    return (new FastExcel(usersGenerator()))->download('file.xlsx');
}

public function usersGenerator() {
    foreach (User::cursor() as $user) {
        yield $user;
    }
}

In order to actually trigger the download from the browser, I have a button that opens the route in a new tab:
document.querySelector("#excel-download-button").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    window.open('/excel-download', '_blank');
});

So the tab is opened for a split second, the download starts and the tab closes.
But I want to skip this behavior of using the new tab.
Is it possible to download it directly from a fetch request?
Something like this:
fetch('/excel-download')
  .then(response => {
    // ... download ...
  });

I couldn't find the way to do that

The idea is to create a hidden button with type download and click on it. In this case, a new window does not open.
function exportStep(request) {
        fetch(request, {
            method: "GET",
            cache: "no-store"
        }).then((response) => {
            return response.json()
        }).then((data) => {
            if (data.file && data.file.length) {
                let link = '/storage/export/' + data.file;
                let name = document.getElementById('courses').dataset.select;
                let downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
                downloadLink.href = link;
                downloadLink.download = name + " ({{date('d.m.Y')}}).xlsx";

                window.parent.document.getElementById('mainloader').classList.remove('show');

                document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
                downloadLink.click();
                document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);

                exportButton.style.display = 'flex';
                exportProgress.style.display = 'none';
                progressTitle.innerText = '0%';
                progressShow.style.maxWidth = '0%';
            } else {
                if (data.step === 'export' || data.step === 'convert') {
                    progressTitle.innerText = data.percenttext;
                    progressShow.style.maxWidth = data.percent+'%';
                    exportStep(data.request);
                }
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Request failed", error, ".")
        });
    }

